# Python: Splitting year number in brackets in a string using regex

Tags: python

Suppose I have a string like str = "The Invisible Man (2020)". In Python I want to split it into a list with **String + Number (year number always at the end of the string)** of Year like below:

`['The Invisible Man', '2020']`

How can I achieve this goal using a regular expression in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `re.split`, which works for this specific string structure:

```
import re

s = "The Invisible Man (2020)"
re.split(r'\s+\((\d+)\)', s)[:2]
# ['The Invisible Man', '2020']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using regexp and named groups. You take longest string followed by space and opening parenthesis and name it *name*. Then you take 4 digit long number inside parenthesis and name it *year*.

Finally make a list as requested in question.

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'(?P<name>([a-zA-Z ]*)) \((?P<year>\d\d\d\d)\)')
m = r.match("The Invisible Man (2020)")
l = [m.group('name'), m.group('year')]
```

Comment: Explanation added. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can write a regex for the whole string, and use `re.search` and `re.search.groups` to get the title and year out of the string:

```
import re

s = "The Invisible Man (2020)"

regex = r"(.+) \((\d+)\)"

title, year = re.search(regex, s).groups()

print('title = "{}", year = "{}"'.format(title, year))
```

Output:

```
title = "The Invisible Man", year = "2020"
```